# Convergent and divergent series

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am studying  the behaviour of product  of a convergent and a divergent infinite series. I found a example in which product series come out to be a  convergent series . But can't get a divergent series
 Does product series  always comes out  to be convergent ?
Or it can be divergent, ?
Please give your views on it

Comment: What's your example?

Comment: I take series 1/n which diverges... And series 1/n^2 which converges and product converges

Comment: It certainly is not the case that the product series always converges. Take $a_n = n$ and $b_n = \frac 1 {n^2}$ Then $\sum a_n$ diverges, $\sum b_n$ converges and $\sum a_nb_n$ diverges. You can make weaker statements though. For example, if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely and $b_n \to 0$ then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't always convergent.  (I assume by "product you mean $\sum a_nb_n$.)

Take $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}n$ as one of the series and $\sum(-1)^n$ as the other.